# Print all words in a Trie data structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, data-structures, tree

In the following code, I have a function `extractWords` which given a simple trie data structure should return a list of words.

I am currently using a recursion (even another way is acceptable) to try to get the words. The  `'*': null,` reppresents the end of the word in the trie.

Current result is ["ble"], which is wrong, I would like to have instead ["ble", "bout"].

I am not able to move to the next path in the tree. Could you please point me out in the right direction? Thanks

[TS Play Ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6g9gJwCZQLxQM7AQSwHYDmA3ALABQoksiSGa1yA2gLqlnmXQAquAcnEmjoA3uShRGAawggAXJmz4CzeTxz9BUAD5Q8AVwA2BtgF825AxGBQAxnoQIIeYBoiq%20AoVFFlxfvwDkAFQB8vpGADRi-n4ARvI%20MTEGCdFJ-m7eaen%20waG6hgZRvjl%20JsWlUOXZSXCpJZV69ZX%20wM0tuSFhhRUdVb2V1Q3pQzmjMWbk5DZweFhQEAAe2ACGNsDwyHToABSKru7qngCU8pu0aAB8WSUzc9aOdggYOLP0ex6Ch64RtvaOznOZxopwYF1Q10Sfju82kIG2UAA8rEAFYQdYAOjhGA%20R0ExzY-ksDwgGEMwAwwK29BYhL8ADNEFAdsSoDh6AAGIhsqAAHig2IxlkIwAAFkRjjckjDrHD6NjGDhWDU2fTmXLUJqoHlJVCko4yQYKRiwHoMKKdk8ARsQXSkjgANQOu1lBYGDDQPUxGVQRb0faeKQyZXDfw4NU7Ra6lVhp0u-VWex4KCPewvWaR35Wpw25BQB0CmQEmNVFUmbLl4aOYBJlOk8kYOmTdglau11PPV54XE-bUBYtkZtTMjh5nZ5yuaO3WbzBD0JardbnHHjlwnOkwuCWIVwAg7BAEqAAeiPfwcObrhusjAARLFLDfmL8AJJQADucEMKAMOGkUGAcBQKKKwAG7QPgWAQCsKC3veEA3r8d6fsAj7kCYQA)

```
type Word = string;
type Words = Word[];

type TriNode = {
  [key: string]: TriNode | null;
};

let currentNode: TriNode = {
        '*': null,
        b: {
          l: {
            e: {
              '*': null,
            },
          },
          o: {
            u: {
              t: {
                '*': null,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };

const extractWords = (triNode: TriNode): Words => {
  const recursion = (triNode: TriNode, currentWord: Word): Words => {
    const keys = Object.keys(triNode);
    let results: Words = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length;) {
      const key = keys[i];
      if (key === '*') {
        results.push(currentWord);
        i++;
      } else {
        const x = triNode[key];
        if (x) {
          i++;
          return recursion(x, currentWord + key);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  };

  return recursion(triNode, '');
};


if (currentNode) {
  const r = extractWords(currentNode);
  console.log(r); // current result ["ble"], I would like to have instead ["ble", "bout"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after the recursive call returns your code performs a `return` and does not allow the surrounding loop to make more iterations.

So replace the following statement:

```
      return recursion(x, currentWord + key);
```

with:

```
      results.push(...recursion(x, currentWord + key));
```

Note that the results will also include "", as you have a `*` key at the top level.

#### Other remarks

- It is a bit odd that you increment the loop variable in the loop body, and not in the `for` heading as is usually done.
- You could use a `for..in` loop.
- This is a nice candidate for a generator function.

That would look like this:

```js
let currentNode = {'*': null,b: {l: {e: {'*': null,},},o: {u: {t: {'*': null,},},},},};

const extractWords = (triNode) => {
  function* recursion(triNode, currentWord) {
    for (const key in triNode) {
      if (key === '*') {
        yield currentWord;
      } else {
        const x = triNode[key];
        if (x) {
          yield* recursion(x, currentWord + key);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return Array.from(recursion(triNode, ''));
};


if (currentNode) {
  const r = extractWords(currentNode);
  console.log(r);
}
```